# Capturing a screenshot of teststack.white window in c# -winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screenshot, white-framework

Can someone help me with code to capture a screenshot of the teststack.white window? I tried the following code

```
Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(new System.Drawing.Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), System.Drawing.Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                }
                bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\Desktop\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
```

This captures a screenshot of the form. If in place of this.bounds , I key in the teststack.white window bounds, it says cannot convert system.windows.rect to system.drawing.rectangle? Can someone provide me with the code to get this sorted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `System.Windows.Rect` is part of WindowsBase.dll (used in WPF, mostly). You are referring  WinForms. What is it, then? How did you get the bounds of that Window (teststack.white window)?

Comment: teststack window has the property window.bounds which returns a windows.rect .

Comment: Then just translate the `Rect` structure to a `Rectangle` structure: `Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(new Point((int)rect.Location.X, (int)rect.Location.Y), new Size((int)rect.Size.Width, (int)rect.Size.Height));`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's easy:

```
Desktop.TakeScreenshot("C:\\white-framework.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

If you need to manipulate the image after capturing it, you can do this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Desktop.CaptureScreenshot();
```